# FastCopyでLinux上からファイルをコピーするとき「GetVolumeInformation ログオン失敗」と表示される

Tags: linux, windows, samba

FastCopyを使ってWindowsとLinux PC間のデータをコピーしたい。

Source:LINUXのPath
DestDir:Windowsの外付けドライブ

「実行」ボタンを押しましたら、下記エラーメッセージが表示されました。

> GetVolumeInformation(ログオン失敗: ユーザー名を認識できないか、またはパスワードが間違っています。

LINUX側の/etc/smb.confを下記のように設定してみましたら、

```ini
[global]
    hosts allow = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (WindowsPC の IP Address)
    security = share

[Share]
    path = /opt/FTS
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    create mode = 0777
    directory mode = 0777
    share modes = yes
```

WindowsからLinuxへコピーができましたが、コピーできたファイルの所有者/グループが **nobody/nobody** となります。
コピーできましたらファイルの所有者/グループはroot/rootにしたいです。

設定方法を教えていただけますか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: FastCopyということは作業はWindows上で行われているのだと思いますが、Linux上のファイルシステムをどのようにしてWindows上から参照しているのでしょうか（例えばSambaによるファイル共有とか）。Source側のファイルはエクスプローラで閲覧したり、メモ帳などの他のソフトで開くことはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: Source側のファイルはエクスプローラで閲覧したり、メモ帳などの他のソフトで開くことはできます。LinuxとWindowsのファイル共有は特に設定していません。先日Winscpを使ってファイルコピーをしました。サイズは大きいから、とても時間がかかりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

所有者を指定(root)する場合はsmb.conf の共有の設定で以下のようにしてください

force user = root 
force group = root

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。